# backward forward windows phone 7 music player

Tags: media-player, windows-phone

What method is used to do backward forward for mediaplayer in windows phone 7. Also how to present the progress bar for current song?
I have look all over [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254868.aspx) but couldn't find any method to use. Any one have suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried? and what dop you mean by "do backward forward for mediaplayer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for a XNA game or a regular application? By adding a playlist to the regular player, using the [MediaHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.mediahistory%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class you can use the build-in controls of the phone. Also to obtain the current position, use the [MediaPlayer.PlayPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.playposition.aspx) property.

For doing a custom implemented UI for the playlist, look into using the [MediaPlayer.Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.queue.aspx).

Comment: this is a regular application, I have look into PlayPosition property, it's only allow get: 
public static TimeSpan PlayPosition { get; } how can I display progress bar or timespan of current song?

Comment: Obviously you would have to calculate it from the song duration. Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.duration.aspx

Comment: Ok here is how I get it, we have MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Duration --> get total play time
MediaPlayer.PlayPosition --> get current position
but this is in Time span class, how can I display it? And I also need a timer also, correct?

Comment: You can display it however you like, that's up to you and your designer skills. As for the UI update, then yes, you should use a DispatcherTimer to invoke a UI update for a set interval, with the recalculated position.

Comment: Thanks you, I have the progress bar implemented. How about fast backward/forward a song? There was only get method, no set...

Comment: I'm not under the impression that such a option is available.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class? In particular, position property can let you position the media to go backward/forward.

Comment: how to have position property to go backward/forward? Can you give me an example?